# Represent a list of elements in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a list of elements in XML.

```
<disposition label="RegulatoryAgency">
    <dispositionDetails code="114" location="243" />
    <dispositionDetails code="79" location="61"/>
</disposition>
```

I want to represent this list in XSD. Below is what I have now.

```
<xs:element name="disposition" type="dispositionList" minOccurs="0"/>

<xs:complexType name="dispositionList">
    <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dispositionDetails" type="DispositionDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DispositionDetails">
    <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="location" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

However it does not work. I get errors like `The content of 'dispositionList' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.` Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'The order of xsd element is relevant.'

1)  annotation?

2) (simpleContent|complexContent|((group|all|choice|sequence))?

3) (attribute|attributeGroup)?

```
<xs:complexType name="dispositionList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dispositionDetails" type="DispositionDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```